# Verbose output from compiler when using inline assembler?

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, arm, inline-assembly

I'm catching a compile failure under ARM with some inline assembler:

```
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -pipe -c sha.cpp
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:779: Error: ARM register expected -- `ror [sp,#20],#31'
{standard input}:799: Error: ARM register expected -- `ror [sp],#31'
{standard input}:848: Error: ARM register expected -- `ror [sp,#4],#31'
```

While not obvious, the code above can be choking on one of four rotates, depending on the CPU features, like if thumb is in effect.

*"standard input"* is not very helpful, and I'm trying to get GCC to provide more information on the offending lines in the source code. `--verbose` to both the compiler driver and assembler does not produce it:

```
g++ --verbose -Wa,--verbose -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -pipe -c sha.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
...
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-g2' '-O2' '-pipe' '-c' '-shared-libgcc'
  '-march=armv4t' '-mfloat-abi=soft' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabi
  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D NDEBUG sha.cpp -quiet -dumpbase sha.cpp -march=armv4t -mfloat-abi=soft
  -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase sha -g2 -O2 -version -o - |
as -v -march=armv4t -mfloat-abi=soft -meabi=5 --verbose -o sha.o
GNU assembler version 2.25.1 (arm-linux-gnueabi) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian)
...
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi/c++/5"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabi"
...
Compiler executable checksum: e1a12b8fe77987e69c757712d6e0213e
{standard input}: Assembler messages:
{standard input}:779: Error: ARM register expected -- `ror [sp,#20],#31'
{standard input}:799: Error: ARM register expected -- `ror [sp],#31'
{standard input}:848: Error: ARM register expected -- `ror [sp,#4],#31'
```

How can I get GCC to print more information, like relevant line numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you don't use -pipe? I would also try -s to generate assembly file instead of binary.

Answer (score 1):

Use the listing option for GNU as, `-ahl` will produce a listing with high level source code mixed with assembler. You will need to pass the `-g` option to gcc, so you need the options `-Wa,-ahl -g`.